# Camel JMS : connection refresh not working (IBM MQ)

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, ibm-mq

I'm using the following endpoint :

```yaml
jms:queue:MY_JMS_QUEUE?transacted=true&recoveryInterval=10000&testConnectionOnStartup=true
```

Everything works well but whenever the MQ connection is lost (due to IBM MQ server restart), the connection refresh does not work.

In my logs i have that :

```
ERROR [c.c.j.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer] []] Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'MY_JMS_QUEUE' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=10000, currentAttempts=0, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'xxx' with connection mode 'Client' ......('MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE')
```

And nothing else, i was expecting to have the same error messages multiples times with currentAttempts=1 then 2... until the MQ is back.

I checked the documentation but i don't see anything else. My configuration:

```
Camel version : 3.11.3
Java: 11.0.8 
Spring boot : 2.5.2
```

Comment: What happens if you have transacted set to false?  When transacted is set to true, the DMLC does not manage the JMS connection, so it is not refreshed on a reconnect attempt.  If you enable TRACE level logging for the IBM MQ classes, I suspect that you will see the same (now broken) JMS connection being used and not refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

As your connection mode is "Client" you can give the MQ automatic JMS client reconnection feature a try. You would need to configure the "ClientReconnectOptions" in the connection factory definition.